Why does split DNS macOS system DNS lookup doesn't match nslookup/host (no external DNS servers)?
This problem seems new to macOS Sequoia and split-dns. I've read and checked all the usual macOS split-dns problems.
On the inside of my network, my-server.synology.me resolves to the private IP address of my server. This is provided by a ubiquity router running dnsmasq. Outside my network, my-server.synology.me is provided by an external DNS server.

Running host my-server.synology.me on the Mac (and on the router) returns the internal address, and the proper DNS server is listed.
Checking System Settings > Network > Ethernet > Details shows the internal DNS server and only the internal DNS server, with a search domain of 'lan'. This is correct. Specifically, I am not including any external DNS servers, all queries must go through my server.
Flushing the DNS cache through the usual sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder does not change anything.
Rebooting does not fix the problem.
scutil --dns shows nothing odd (see attached at bottom)
No proxies or VPN are configured.

Again, this seems new since my macOS Sequoia update. It seems like the Mac is picking up the address from an external DNS server, not the internal one, but I can't for the life of me figure out where/why.
Any thoughts on what to look for?
$ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : lan
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.88.1
  if_index : 6 (en0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : lan
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.88.1
  if_index : 6 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  search domain[0] : lan
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.88.1
  if_index : 14 (en1)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)


Slaps head. In case any of the rest of you make the same mistake:
I had recently enabled "Limit IP address tracking" on the Mac's Ethernet interface, which causes DNS queries to be routed through Apple's servers as well. Turning it off fixed everything.
